# For chain of comments, flag once only or flag all?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, comment-flags

I was just found some comments about post Id [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333333) and believe they are to chatty:

> - This answer's ID is 33333333, by the way.
>   - @MadaraUchiha I don't understand.
>   - Press the "share" link and observe the URL you get.
>   - Ah, I didn't know about that. Thanks.

The problem is: should we flag all posts? Or flag the first one only?

Comment: Use a custom flag instead, type "Please clean up all comments".

Comment: Might be a dupe Meta question. If not, this has been discussed before at least in some capacity somewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a custom flag on *one* of the comments, explaining the situation.

Then a mod can clean up the thread.

Comment: The comments appear to have been removed already, though.

Comment: I usually flag the question or answer rather than an indivudual comment.